# Django and RabbitMQ setup

Tags: django, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have a django app deployed on multiple VMs behind a load balancer. On each django. I want to setup celery and RabbitMQ for the app. Each django app would be running a celery worker, and some of the VMs should be running RabbitMQ in a cluster setup and if a celery worker executes a task others shouldn't execute the same task. Is this approach for setting up celery and RabbitMQ good. Can anyone guide me to how this can be setup (Configurations, tutorial, etc.)?

Comment: Is there any special need to setup `rabbitmq` and `celery` separate for each VM? I think you should have a central server for `celery` and `rabbimq`

Comment: I want to setup multiple celery broker because each of my django app would be adding tasks and I want to do load balancing across these celery broker. As for the RabbitMQ I want a cluster setup as it avoids a single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

For a better use case what you can do is run only a single RabbitMQ instance so if any celery worker can pick the task from queue and after picking up the task it will be removed from the queue so that it would not executed multiple times. Or another thing what you can do is to run celery and rabbitmq on a single separate VM and increase the number of workers of celery while running celery if this helps in your use case.